# Can't figure out how to set up java debug adapter Neovim

Tags: neovim, debugging, filetype-java

I've been getting into Neovim more and I quite like it so far. I need to use java for university in a couple months so I've been setting that up. I've gotten java to *run* pretty good, but I'm running into issues setting up the debugger.

My config is based off [kickstart.nvim](https://github.com/nvim-lua/kickstart.nvim), I cloned it a couple weeks ago and decided to go off on my own from [there](https://github.com/NicoElbers/nvim-config).

I tried to follow a guide to [setup the java debugger](https://alpha2phi.medium.com/neovim-for-beginners-java-debugging-f141dc2bca96)  after a bit of trouble shooting I managed to download `java-debug` and `vscode-java-test` using mason (which was 10x easier than the way they did it, I had a lot of issues). Afterwards the guide said to put the following code in a file, which to my knowledge attaches jdtls to the buffer.

```lua
...

local HOME = os.getenv "HOME"

-- Debugger installation location
local DEBUGGER_LOCATION = HOME .. "/.local/share/nvim"

-- Debugging
local bundles = {
  vim.fn.glob(
    DEBUGGER_LOCATION .. "/java-debug/com.microsoft.java.debug.plugin/target/com.microsoft.java.debug.plugin-*.jar"
  ),
}
vim.list_extend(bundles, vim.split(vim.fn.glob(DEBUGGER_LOCATION .. "/vscode-java-test/server/*.jar"), "\n"))


local config = {
  ...
  
  on_attach = require("config.lsp").on_attach,

  -- If you don't plan on using the debugger or other eclipse.jdt.ls plugins you can remove this
  init_options = {
    bundles = bundles,
  },
}
...
```

I tried to change that code and put it in my own config, with a notable change being that I changed the path `vim.fn.glob()` gets because it didn't line up with the files I had, the result of that is the following (from line 500 in `init.lua` in my config if anyone wants to see that)

```lua
local HOME = os.getenv "HOME"

local DEBUGGER_LOCATION = HOME .. "/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages"

local jdtlsBundles = {
  vim.fn.glob(
    DEBUGGER_LOCATION .. "/java-debug-adapter/extension/server/com.microsoft.java.debug.plugin-*.jar"
  ),
}
vim.list_extend(jdtlsBundles, vim.split(vim.fn.glob(DEBUGGER_LOCATION .. "/java-test/extension/server/*.jar"), "\n"))

local serverSettings = {
  -- clangd = {},
  -- gopls = {},
  pyright = {},
  -- rust_analyzer = {},
  -- tsserver = {},
  jdtls = {
    init_options = {
      bundles = jdtlsBundles
    }
  },

  lua_ls = {
    Lua = {
      workspace = { checkThirdParty = false },
      telemetry = { enable = false },
    },
  },
}
-- Setup neovim lua configuration
require('neodev').setup()

-- nvim-cmp supports additional completion capabilities, so broadcast that to servers
local capabilities = vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities()
capabilities = require('cmp_nvim_lsp').default_capabilities(capabilities)

-- Ensure the servers above are installed
local mason_lspconfig = require 'mason-lspconfig'

mason_lspconfig.setup {
  ensure_installed = vim.tbl_keys(serverSettings),
}


mason_lspconfig.setup_handlers {
  function(server_name)
    require('lspconfig')[server_name].setup {
      capabilities = capabilities,
      on_attach = on_attach,
      settings = serverSettings[server_name],
    }
  end,
}
```

Then finally the guide says to copy the following code in a file `/lsp/init.lua` so I assume that's to setup the lsp.

```lua
function M.on_attach(client, bufnr)
  ...
 
  -- Configure for jdtls
  if client.name == "jdt.ls" then
    require("jdtls").setup_dap { hotcodereplace = "auto" }
    require("jdtls.dap").setup_dap_main_class_configs()
    vim.lsp.codelens.refresh()
  end
end
```

From my understanding the last function in the previous code block does that, so in the `on_attach` function that it calls I copied this code directly. (line 480 in `init.lua` in my config).

Kickstart.nvim itself already has some setup done for nvim-dap, copying it all here seems overboard but this seems like the relevant part:

```lua
        require('mason-nvim-dap').setup {
            automatic_setup = true,

            handlers = {},

            ensure_installed = {
                'delve',
                'java-debug',
                'vscode-java-test',
            },
        }
```

as far as I remember I never changed this, but `'java-debug'` and `'vs-code-java-test'` aren't in base kickstart.nvim so I may have added those and forgotten.

From this point, the guide suggests things should be working, which they half are. When I'm in a java project, pressing F7 does give me a few windows that seems to be debug related (albeit that they're empty) however if I try to `continue`/run the debugger I get the error `` no configuration found for `java`. You need to  add configs to `dap.configurations.java` (see `:h dap-configuration`) `` The guide suggests to run the command `:JdtRefreshDebugConfigs`, but that command doesn't exist for me.

And there I'm stuck right now, I've looked around a little for ways to solve my problem, but frankly I don't even know where to look, so I just decided to make a post here (this is  a cross-post from a post on Neovim discourse https://neovim.discourse.group/t/cant-seem-to-figure-out-how-to-set-up-the-java-debug-adapter/4216). If anyone knows how to point me into the right direction, or knows what I'm doing wrong, any help is much appreciated! (please keep in mind that I'm pretty close to a complete beginner, so this could be a simple mistake I made)

Answer (score 0):

you should change the client name to 'jdtls',

```lua
 -- Configure for jdtls
  if client.name == "jdtls" then
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This answer would be better if you [edit]ed to include details (teach 'em to fish), such as how someone could figure this out for themselves next time they have an issue with the `client.name` property